# calculation of current in a resistor

Tags: current, resistors, physics

I have a little bit confusion about the current in the 40 ohm resistor given in the picture below. Will the current be zero?

[image]

Comment: It's either a stupid question or a trick question unless you have more information about the voltage sources.

Comment: What the heck? That's one dead short.

Comment: As drawn the circuit is violating the KVL law  on the loop including the two voltage sources.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws

Comment: Set bottom node's voltage to 0V, arbitrarily. You get to do that for exactly one node. Then the top node is both +10V and -10V, simultaneously. Since the two values can't be equal, without using a completely different system of algebra and symbol set anyway, the top node's voltage is inconsistent and the question is unsound.

Comment: See that circuit is equavalent of a short circuited 20 V source and the resistor across the poles. This way it is more obvious that it is nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnIr5I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) The circuit redrawn with + at the top and - at the bottom. (b) A real-world setup with internal resistance.*

The redrawn circuit of Figure 1 clearly shows that the voltage sources are shorted out.

A theoretical ideal analysis can't be performed because an ideal voltage source can't have an output voltage and both its terminals at the same potential.

In the real case with two identical batteries there would be no voltage across R2.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in the real case, there's no such thing as two identical batteries.

Comment: But ideally in the real case ... or really in the ideal case ... maybe there is? In any case voltage across R2 won't be the problem.

Answer (score -6):

The current in resistor by Ohm's law is \$I = \frac{U}{R}\$
$$ 
U = 10 V \\
R = 40\Omega \\
I = \frac{10}{40} = 0.25 A 
$$
Both sources are of equal voltage, will deliver 50% each.

Comment: Don't think it's that simple. Ever thought about the battery going through another battery?

Comment: @Manmohan: The batteries polarities are reversed.